# Android: subscribed channel for particular user on youtube

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am working on a app in which I need subscribed channels for a particular user and also details about those channels. I don't know how to do it.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: @Assaf, you edited the question, but I believe changed the meaning. I think yashka wanted to know the channels already subscribed to – yashka, please clarify.

Comment: Ho... I guess I understood it differently 'somehow'... Sorry, please feel free to correct me :)

Comment: @Christopher Creutzig: absolutely.. it changed the question completely.. but no issues i will edit it again.

Comment: I have edited it again, please check it.

Comment: Are you trying to find the channels the logged in user subscribed to or the channels who subscribed to user's channel?

Comment: Currently I am looking for the first one i.e. channels the logged ion user subscribed to but it will great if I got answer for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer. We need to use youtube.subscriptions.list for this.

Request message will be like this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

And the response for that will be:

```
200 OK
```

If you want to try it, you can click [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.subscriptions.list).

For more reference check [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list).